# Why webdriver returns the same element for differend id and xPath index?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I've got stuck on a problem with [chromedriver](/questions/tagged/chromedriver): list of web-elements returns only first item (also tried to complete the task with [geckodriver](/questions/tagged/geckodriver) but result is the same).

The structure of grid created by [sencha](/questions/tagged/sencha) is:

```
div-containers
    table (as row)
        tr (only one)
            td (as column/cell)
            td (as column/cell)
            ...
    table (as row)
    table (as row)
```

Here is HTML-code:

```
<div id="grid-1612-body" data-ref="body" class="x-panel-body x-grid-no-row-lines x-grid-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default x-noborder-rl" role="presentation" style="width: 1069px; left: 0px; height: 585px; top: 29px;">
    <div class="x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable x-scroller" role="rowgroup" id="gridview-1625" tabindex="0" data-componentid="gridview-1625" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; margin: 0px; width: 1069px; height: 583px;">
        <div class="x-tab-guard x-tab-guard-after" tabindex="-1" data-tabindex-value="0" data-tabindex-counter="1"></div>
        <div class="x-grid-item-container" role="presentation" style="width: 1052px;">
            <table id="gridview-1625-record-218" role="presentation" data-boundview="gridview-1625" data-recordid="218" data-recordindex="0" class="x-grid-item" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width:0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="  x-grid-row" role="row">
                        <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-templatecolumn-1614 x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="templatecolumn-1614">
                            <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:;">
                                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="resources/pir-core/images/icons/star.gray.svg" title="Соглашение создано">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-debtAmount x-unselectable" style="width:130px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="debtAmount">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                                    <b>9,36 $</b>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1616 x-unselectable" style="width:80px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1616">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:;">66 month</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-debtAmountsByActionTypes x-unselectable" style="width:40px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="debtAmountsByActionTypes">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:;">
                                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-debtorName x-wrap-cell x-unselectable" style="width: 135px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="debtorName" id="ext-element-43">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:;" id="ext-element-42">Sherlock Holmes</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1619  x-wrap-cell x-unselectable" style="width: 135px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="gridcolumn-1619">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:;">Baker Street 221B</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-ownersNumber x-unselectable" style="width:80px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="ownersNumber" id="ext-element-39">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:;">1</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-lastPay x-unselectable" style="width:165px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="lastPay">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">1 532,02 $</td>
                                                <td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: right; color: silver;">117 days</td>
                                                <td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-templatecolumn-1622 x-unselectable" style="width: 67px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="templatecolumn-1622">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:;">
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color: silver;">2596949  </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-callStatus x-pir-cursor-pointer x-unselectable" style="width:90px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="callStatus">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:;">
                                    <div class="call-status ">
                                        <div>
                                            <i class="call-status-icon"></i>0
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="color: silver;">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-mailStatus x-pir-cursor-pointer x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable" style="width:90px;" role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-columnid="mailStatus">
                                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:;">
                                    <div class="post-status ">
                                        <div>
                                            <i class="post-status-icon"></i>0
                                        </div>
                                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table id="gridview-1625-record-219" role="presentation" data-boundview="gridview-1625" data-recordid="219" data-recordindex="1" class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-alt" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width:0">
                    ...
                </table>
                <table id="gridview-1625-record-220" role="presentation" data-boundview="gridview-1625" data-recordid="220" data-recordindex="2" class="x-grid-item" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width:0">
                    ...
                </table>
                <table id="gridview-1625-record-221" role="presentation" data-boundview="gridview-1625" data-recordid="220" data-recordindex="2" class="x-grid-item" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width:0">
                    ...
                </table>
                <table id="gridview-1625-record-222" role="presentation" data-boundview="gridview-1625" data-recordid="220" data-recordindex="2" class="x-grid-item" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=";width:0">
                    ...
                </table>
                ...
                <div id="loadmask-1660-msgTextEl" data-ref="msgTextEl" class="x-mask-msg-text" role="presentation">Loading...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And no matter how I try to get second element (or whatever not-first) there is only first element returned:

```
// getting n-th item of WebElements list
List<WebElement> debtorElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='grid-1612-body']/div/div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table"));
debtorElements.get(2).findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-columnid='debtorName']/div")).getText()

// by xPath with index
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='grid-1612-body']/div/div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table[2]")).findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div")).getText()
// by xPath with id
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='gridview-1625-record-219']")).findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div")).getText()
```

Chrome browser: Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official build), (64 bit).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `//` you are telling the `WebDriver` to look from the root node (`<html>`). Use `.` to tell it to look from location

```
debtorElements.get(2).findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@data-columnid='debtorName']/div")).getText()
                                            ^ add this
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, but why should I use `//` and `.` at the same time? They are contradictory, conflicting... But still it works. And `./tr/td...` or `./table/tr/td...` does not work

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko I guess you can use one `/`, but you can't use just `.`. This is the `xpath` syntax.

Comment: Ok, it should be `./tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div`. I have missed `tbody`. So `.` "changes" root node to the current one

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we copy the Xpath using "Copy Xpath" in Chrome, it is not completely copied. I mean it completely gives the Xpath but not the index of element. we have to use manual indexing. try this if it works:

```
// by xPath with index
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='grid-1612-body']/div/div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table[2]")).findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div[your webelement index]")).getText()

//Same will be the case with Id
```

Also i hope you know about Iteration of elements using whatever loop you want, so go with that too
try out..

Comment: I see you added `/div[your webelement index]` but there is only one dive inside 5th <td> so it is not a solution. BTW I did not copy xPath from Chrome. And the problem is at the level of `/table[i]`

Comment: have you tried foreach loop on each element? @IvanGerasimenko

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are trying:

```
debtorElements.get(2).findElement(By.xpath("//td[@data-
columnid='debtorName']/div")).getText()
```

This is probably going to get text for the first element. You could do something like:

```
foreach(el in debtorElements)
{
    el.getText();
}
```

This way you will try getting the text for each element within your list. I program in C#, so excuse any syntax errors.